# How to modify the information field passed by the PCI device to the kernel during initialization?

Tags: linux-kernel, gpu, linux-device-driver, pci-e

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445413/how-does-pci-pcie-devices-init-register-themselves-in-the-linux-kernel), PCI/PCIe devices (such as GPUs) in the system need to go through an initialization process before being used:

1. The OS kernel obtains the values in PCI configuration registers.
2. The OS passes the obtained value to the corresponding device driver through `struct pci_dev`.
3. The device driver registers PCI/PCIe devices according to its own logic.

**Which piece of kernel code performs the second step?**

**Is there any software method to modify the PCI/PCIe device information field passed to device driver by the OS in the first or second step?**

Comment: 1. _drivers/pci/probe.c_. 2. Yes, there is the way for modifying some fields.

Comment: There is code in *drivers/pci/quirks.c* for handling quirks of miscellaneous, known quirky devices. The quirks cannot be implemented in a driver module for a custom PCI device because it is too late by the time the driver's probe function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Linux, You can change some registers read values with the [setpci](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setpci) command, but the absolute recommendation is to use it only for debug, learning needs etc.

The initialization process (a.k.a Enumeration) is pretty complex and has lots of internal dependencies.